# What's problem with multi monitor usage in rdc7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I want to use dual monitors with remote desktop on windows 7 ultimate. Host machine is win server 2008 r2. I open the run window type mstsc /multimon and press enter, also "use all my monitors for the remote session" is checked.By this way RDC is opening but only in one monitor.Do I need to do any changes on host too? I have tried /span attribute and it worked but I don't want it.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem from a windows xp client using mstsc 7.0. I see your question hasn't been answered since May of 2010 so I'm losing hope :-D

Comment: I am working with 5 remote servers and only one of them supports multi monitor usage. All of them have win 2008 r2. I think the hardware must support multi monitor otherwise nothing to do with that. But in the other hand the server that supports multi monitor has the most basic hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Does the server have multiple monitor support enabled? [According to this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125234108/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx), you can find this setting in Remote Desktop Configuration → RDP-Tcp → Client Settings, then here you set the maximum number of monitors per session (it may be set to 1 currently). There are also two group policies listed in that article that control the number and resolution of monitors allowed.

Comment: I have looked that article and tried every method mentioned there but none of them worked. (except changing Win32_TSClientSetting)

Answer (score 1):

The Server [ or the computer you are connecting to] has to be either Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise. Only those 2 will allow the use of the multimon switch.

Comment: What about Windows Server 2008 R2?